# How to Simulate a new user on each iteration

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, loadrunner, vugen

Need to perform load testing for the 1000 virtual users. But due to lack of  users credentials cannot perform it. So can any one explain me how to simulate a new user on each iterations. I have already enabled the `Simulate a new user on each iteration` and also enabled the `Clear cache on each iteration` but still getting the same session id for the multiple iterations.

We have SSO integrated with our application and just created the simple `Sign In` and `Sign Out` scenario under `Action.c` with 4 iterations.

Below is the logs which i am getting after executing the script. For each iterations, the session id is remaining same

#### Iteration 1:

```
Action.c(110): ************** SESSION ID ************** : 1e9e644f-7023-4641-b53d-4a8db900a8c9
```

#### Iteration 2:

```
Action.c(110): ************** SESSION ID ************** : 1e9e644f-7023-4641-b53d-4a8db900a8c9
```

#### Iteration 3:

```
Action.c(110): ************** SESSION ID ************** : 1e9e644f-7023-4641-b53d-4a8db900a8c9
```

#### Iteration 4:

```
Action.c(110): ************** SESSION ID ************** : 1e9e644f-7023-4641-b53d-4a8db900a8c9
```

**And my Run time setting looks like below:**

[image: Run time setting looks]

Comment: You need to correlate the session ID. Please read about correlations in LoadRunner.

Comment: @Buzzy, i have correlated and still getting same session id for each iterations. If its not correlated then script would have been failed.

Comment: What happens when you try it in the browser?

Comment: Getting different session id's.

Comment: It is hard to tell what is going on without looking at the script but it could be that if you are using the same credentials for each iteration the server optimizes something to use the same session regardless of what you did in the client.

Comment: Nope i am not using same credentials. I am using 2 different credentials and kept 4 iterations. If possible please look into the code https://gist.github.com/tejas1493/540ab8e39a1ab21d560a3872667be315

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171252/discussion-between-ben-bean-and-buzzy).

Answer (score 1):

is it possible, that your app-server runs behind a loadbalancer? We have sometimes trouble with sticky-sessions during loadtesting, because requesting from the same IP, so the sessions is cached on the proxy/LB.
Or maybe you found a bug in your app...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your script here https://gist.github.com/tejas1493/540ab8e39a1ab21d560a3872667be315 you are logging the client_id parameter that you have correlated when landing on the login page.

By the looks of your login request it is using spring and openid. With openid the client_id is a unique identifier for the client, so will always be the same and is not related to the individual session.

https://connect2id.com/learn/openid-connect